# Running Enumerable multiple times if the data source remain unchanged

Tags: c#

I understand that `IEnumerable` might have a risk to return different result on multiple run.
But, is that still a problem if we sure the underlying record set will never change in between and the sequence of the loop doesn't matter at all ?

It's such a shame to call `ToList` / `ToArray` everywhere without any consideration that it's just a "possible" risk. R# or VS can simply mark it as error if it should never happened.

Is that really no exception at all? 
We should never iterate IEnumerable multiple times?

This is what actually happened. 
In a single threaded environment.

```
void Main()
{
    var result = GetFile(new [] {path1, path2})  // hardcoded path
}

IList<SomeFile> GetFiles(IEnumerable<string> filePaths)
{
    var paths = filePaths.ToArray();   // <-- why we have to do this ?

    foreach(var path In paths)
        // Throw exception if the path not exist.
    foreach (var path In paths)
        // Process and return a list of file
}
```

I understand it makes not much difference as the collection is so small but we are at the beginning of implementing a project that required to deal with big collection of static data. This kinda practice might be a big problem if apply to all areas without considering whether if it is necessary or not.

Comment: _"and the sequence of the loop doesn't matter at all"_ what does that mean? In general it might be safe to always enumerate it if the underlying source doesn't change, it might even be desired, but it always comes with a cost. If it's just a variable someone might overloook that it's not yet "materialized". Put the query into a method and you don't get the resharper warning.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you're describing?  Sometimes calling `.ToList()` also carries a risk, if you're materializing from a slower data source a large number of records that aren't going to be needed.

Comment: If your code doesn't work with indexers and whatsoever then there is no real reason in calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` as it'll lead to multiple enumeration of `IEnumerable` in most cases. Also worth mentioning that these methods create *copy* of underlying enumerable and if you don't need one, then it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The concern of getting different result on second iteration is a distant second to a much more realistic performance concern. Unless your `IEnumerable<T>` is actually a collection in memory, you are running the risk of having to reproduce it each time you enumerate. This could be very costly:

- If `IEnumerable<T>` comes from another LINQ expression, you spend CPU cycles to recompute the same thing,
- If `IEnumerable<T>` comes from the database, you may end up re-reading the data from the server,
- If `IEnumerable<T>` comes from a file, you will re-read the file.

None of the above have an effect on correctness, but it may dramatically decrease the speed, especially for large data sets. Since memory is relatively cheap these days, and garbage collection system is pretty reliable, temporarily saving collections in a list or an array is an inexpensive way to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in-memory collection and not abstract enumerable object - just use appropriate interface (IReadOnlyCollection, IReadOnlyList, etc.) instead of IEnumerable. If you use IEnumerable you should assume that it can be **any** IEnumerable implementation.